# angular http request doesn't work but on postman works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, angular-http

I'm trying to make an http get request with the following url:

```
 private materialsURL2='https://localhost:5001/api/material';

setPrice(id: any, price: any): Observable<any> {

  const url = `${this.materialsURL2}/${id}/price/${price}`;


 return this.http.get<any>(url,httpOptions).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log(`updated material price id=${id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateMaterialPrice'))
        );
      }
```

But nothing happens. If I open the network section in the browser there is no record of the request. If I use the same URL in postman it does the request correctly.

Comment: follow this [link](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Be sure you have the Network section open **before** this is meant to have occurred (Edge, for instance, doesn't show you network requests that ran before you opened the tab). This sounds like a cross-origin issue. Is your page served from `localhost:5001`? If not, does `localhost:5001` return the necessary CORS headers to allow requests from wherever your page is running from?

Comment: @Abhishek - Blind links are not useful. What, *specifically*, about that documentation are you referring the OP to? Did you see something they're doing wrong? If so, *say what that is* when providing the link.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for advice i got it your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription to the observable is missing. Without  calling subscribe on the observable nothing will be executed of the underlying chain.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never subscribed to the get request. The request will fire once you subscribe to it.

```
return this.http.get<any>(url,httpOptions).pipe(
  tap(_ => this.log(`updated material price id=${id}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateMaterialPrice'))
).subscribe((result) => {
  console.log('now it should work', result);
})
```

See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get